# unlock key lock programmatically in Android 4.0

Tags: android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

How can I unlock key lock programmatically in Android 4.0?

```
 mKeyGuardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    mLock = mKeyGuardManager.newKeyguardLock("activity_classname");
    mLock.disableKeyguard();
```

This code seems to be not working in Android 4.0. In second line newKeylock method is depreciated.